# "...,denn von Einbildungskraft Welt er normalerweise gar nichts"-no action verb

Tags: verb, meaning-in-context

Here is a sentence taken from a book:

"Er hoffte, sich diese Dinge nur einzubilden, und das war neu für ihn, **denn von Einbildungskraft Welt er normalerweise gar nichts.**"

I'm curious as to why there's no action verb in the highlighted clause.

Comment: How did you come across the sentence? Did you read it, or did you hear it for example in an audio book? Because I'd reckon this to be a typo, a wrong transcription or something similar. The sentence probably was supposed to be "... denn von Einbildungskraft hält er normalerweise gar nichts", which would translate to something like "... because he normally takes a very dim view of imagination".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This must be a copying error, because the sentence as it stands with **Welt** makes no sense whatsoever and is ungrammatical. It is very likely that the following was intended:

> **Er** hoffte, sich diese Dinge nur einzubilden, und das war neu für ihn, denn von Einbildungskraft **hält** er normalerweise gar nichts.

The phrase

- viel/wenig/nichts etc. von etwas halten<sup>1</sup>

means something like

- to think much/little/nothing etc. of something

---

<sup>1</sup> see [meaning 12. for entry *halten* at the DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/halten#d-1-12-2)

Comment: Als Anmerkung: Ich glaube, "hielt" statt "hält" würde grammatisch noch besser passen, und als falsches Scannen (OCR oder Handschrift) passt "W" auch etwas besser zu einem falsch gelesenen "hi".

Comment: @HalvarF So steht's auch in meiner Ausgabe. Hier scheint Duolingo falsch kopiert zu haben: https://www.lingq.com/de/deutsch-lernen-online/courses/1130019/2-ein-junge-uberlebt-1-15105324/